# Passing a function between multiple react native components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner React Native Developer working on a project with the following structure of components
[image]

The problem I am having is that I have buttons located in the footer component that needs to call a function located in component 2. I'm just wondering what would be the best way to handle this situation. My first instinct would be to move the function to Page and then pass it down to Footer and Component 2 but from a readability perspective it makes it very unclear what the function itself is doing, and as this is code someone else has written I'm unsure if I would want to make such dramatic changes to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Context with a memoized function with useCallback and wrap   with yout context provider

Then you could import that context in whatever component inside Page

like

```
import {createContext,useCallback} from 'react'

const myContext = createContext(()=>{})

const {Provider} = myContext

const AppWrapper = ({children}) =>{
const myFunction = useCallback(()=>{
// do something
}, [])


return (
<Provider value={myFunction}>
{children}
</Provider>
)
}

// in your app file
<AppWrapper>
  <App/>
</AppWrapper>
```

Now you can use your function in whereever component inside Page lik

```
import {useContext} from 'react'

const MyComponent = () =>{
const myFunction = useContext(myContext)

return <>...</>
}
```

Comment: I don't know how is your feature exacly but, redux-saga also could help